# Uber "generate a deeplink" universal link is opening the app but not with the pre-defined drop off parameters

Tags: uber-api

The universal link that was generated by [the 'generate a deeplink' page](https://developer.uber.com/products/ride-requests-deeplink) used to work where when the link is clicked, it would open the Uber app with the drop off location already defined. I noticed over the past few months this changed, and it now opens the app but without the drop off parameter. I would need to manually enter it when opening the app now.

Here is the universal link that is generated from Uber's deep link generator.

```
https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&client_id=ryqQKpFbKNjgnqJANfdessXXXXXXXXXX&pickup=my_location&dropoff[formatted_address]=33%20Yonge%20Street%2C%20Toronto%2C%20ON%2C%20Canada&dropoff[latitude]=43.647605&dropoff[longitude]=-79.376650
```

I thought it might be a bug from Uber but after a few months it has still not resolved. Does anyone know how I can make the universal link work with the following parameters?

Pick up location: my_location

Drop off location: [latitude]=43.647605 [longitude]=-79.376650

Formatted Address / Nickname: 33%20Yonge%20Street%2C%20Toronto%2C%20ON%2C%20Canada

Thank you!